# Как сделать отображение сущности на несколько таблиц в Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Пытаюсь выполнить отображение сущности `Student` на несколько таблиц: `students`, `addresses`, `hobbies`. Ключи в таблицах `addresses` и `hobbies` являются также внешними и ссылаются на первичный ключ таблицы `students`. То есть, таблица `students` основная, а остальные - вспомогательные.
Вот описания классов:

**Student**

```
package entity;    
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
@SecondaryTables({
        @SecondaryTable(name = "hobbies"),
        @SecondaryTable(name = "addresses"),
})
public class Student {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Column(table = "hobbies")
    private String hobby;

    @Column(table = "addresses")
    @Embedded
    private Address address;

    public Student(){}

    public Student(String name, String hobby, Address address){
        this.name = name;
        this.hobby = hobby;
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

**Address**

```
package entity;    
import javax.persistence.*;

@Embeddable
public class Address {

    @Column(name="street")
    private String street;

    public Address(){}

    public Address(String street){
        this.street = street;
    }
}
```

В результате, поле `String hobby` класса `Student` отображается в отдельную таблицу `hobbies` без проблем, а вот `Address address` отобразить не получается. То есть таблица `addresses` создаётся, и внешний ключ в ней прописан, но данные не поступают (таблица пустая). Кроме того, в таблице `addresses` присутствует только одно поле - `student_id`, а поле `street` почему-то отсутствует.

Создаются данные как-то так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StudentService service = new StudentService();
    try {
        Student student = service.create(
                new Student("Вася", "Лыжи", new Address("ул. Ленина"))
        );
        Student student2 = service.create(
                new Student("Петя", "Хоккей", new Address("ул. Фрунзе"))
        );
    } catch (DBException e){
        System.out.println("что-то пошло не так");
    }
    DBService.close();
}
```

Это слой сервиса:

```
package service;

import dao.*;
import exception.DBException;
import entity.Student;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import javax.persistence.NoResultException;

public class StudentService {

    public StudentService(){}

    public Student create(Student student) throws DBException {
        Transaction transaction = DBService.getTransaction();
        try {
            StudentDao studentDao = DaoFactory.getStudentDao();
            Long studentId = studentDao.create(student);
            student = studentDao.get(studentId);
            transaction.commit();
            return student;
        } catch (HibernateException | NoResultException | NullPointerException e) {
            DBService.transactionRollback(transaction);
            throw new DBException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Почему таблица `addresses` пустая и как сделать так, чтобы у неё была правильная структура (было поле `street`) и она заполнялась данными?
При выполнении никаких предупреждений или ошибок нет (но отсутствуют запросы на вставку данных в таблицу `addresses`):

```
Hibernate: drop table addresses if exists
Hibernate: drop table hobbies if exists
Hibernate: drop table students if exists
Hibernate: create table addresses (student_id bigint not null, primary key (student_id))
Hibernate: create table hobbies (hobby varchar(255), student_id bigint not null, primary key (student_id))
Hibernate: create table students (student_id bigint generated by default as identity, street varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (student_id))
Hibernate: alter table addresses add constraint FKqq1nt3g94upydb2qt72xhnk7y foreign key (student_id) references students
Hibernate: alter table hobbies add constraint FKmcdfc4qw94xl2a8ak5kct6rys foreign key (student_id) references students
мар 15, 2019 5:43:34 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@3d9f6567'
Hibernate: insert into students (student_id, street, name) values (null, ?, ?)
мар 15, 2019 5:43:34 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:h2:./h2db]
Hibernate: insert into hobbies (hobby, student_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select student_id from students where student_id =? for update
Hibernate: insert into students (student_id, street, name) values (null, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into hobbies (hobby, student_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select student_id from students where student_id =? for update

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: не делать ее `@Embeddable`, а связать через связь один к одному. `@Embedded` говорит о том что в Java коде это две разные сущности, но в бд таблица одна.

Comment: @Tsyklop, но почему поле `hobby` без проблем отображается в отдельную таблицу без всяких "один-к-одному"? Если делать отображение списка или мапы данных, помеченных `@Embeddable`, то новая таблица и данные в ней создаются без проблем. Как нужно исправить классы по вашему мнению?

Comment: У Embedded уберите Column и поставьте @AttributeOverride(name="street", column=@Column(table="addresses"))

Comment: @golubtsoff у поля `hobby` нет аннотации `@Embedded`. попробуйте ее добавить и поглядите что будет. Или как подсказывает человек выше.

Comment: @Serodv, спасибо, дружище, работает. При этом без разницы, есть `@Embedded` перед address, или нет. Замечу, что класс Address должен быть помечен аннотацией @Embeddable, иначе придётся прописывать сущность в конфигурации менеджера со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

Comment: @Tsyklop, да, вы правы, если поставить `@Embedded` перед `hobby`, то работать не будет, что странно. В книге [ссылка](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/147137095/) про `@Embedded` сказано "Это альтернатива аннотации `@Embeddable` - достаточно отметить что-то одно: либо класс компонента, либо свойство класса-владельца." В примере выше класс `Address` должен обязательно быть помечен `Embeddable` (или перед полем `address` поставить `Embedded`), иначе работать не будет. Получается, `@Embedded` работает по-разному с `hobby` и с `address` из-за их типов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хотел бы дополнить комментарий @Serodv (за который ему огромнейшее спасибо), для случая, когда класс `Address` содержит несколько полей.

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Embeddable
public class Address {

    @Column(name="street")
    private String street;

    @Column(name="building")
    private int building;

    public Address(){}

    public Address(String street, int building){
        this.street = street;
        this.building = building;
    }
}
```

В этом случае класс `Student` выглядит так:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
@SecondaryTables({
        @SecondaryTable(name = "hobbies"),
        @SecondaryTable(name = "addresses"),
})
public class Student {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Column(table = "hobbies")
    private String hobby;

    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name="street", column=@Column(table="addresses")),
            @AttributeOverride(name="building", column=@Column(table="addresses"))
    })
    private Address address;

    public Student(){}

    public Student(String name, String hobby, Address address){
        this.name = name;
        this.hobby = hobby;
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Здесь стоит обратить внимание, что класс `Address` должен быть помечен аннотацией `@Embeddable`, иначе в его нужно будет прописывать в менеджере сущностей со всеми вытекающими (добавлять поле Id, ставить аннотацию @OneToOne...). Можно вместо этого поставить аннотацию `@Embedded` в классе `Student` перед полем `Address address` (можно поставить обе аннотации, но зачем засорять код).

Для отображения в отдельную таблицу класса, содержащего несколько полей, нужно использовать аннотацию `@AttributeOverrides`.

**ВАЖНО!**
В строке `@AttributeOverride(name="street", column=@Column(table="addresses"))` слово `street` нужно писать так, как названо поле в классе `Address`, т.е. все буквы в нижнем регистре. При этом неважно, как написано это поле в аннотации `@Column(name="street")` в классе `Address`.

Аналогично с `@AttributeOverride(name="building", column=@Column(table="addresses"))`. В противном случае в отдельных таблицах `hobbies` и `addresses` не будет полей кроме единственного `student_id`. Все поля останутся в таблице `students`.

Видимо, это баг Hibernate (используется версия 5.2.12.Final)